# Not getting the internship review

Tags: communication, performance-reviews

I made a short internship in march. My "mentor" (the guy responsible for me) wrote a review and handed it to someone else who should look over it. I then went to her office and asked if I can take it with me home immediately or if I will get it per mail. She said she hasn't had time yet and I'll get it in the mail.

Two weeks ago I phoned her and asked about the review and she said that the review is really great, but she had some minor changes and handed it back to my mentor so he can look over the changes. Also she asked if I need it urgently. I replied no, because it isn't very urgent (and I thought it wouldn't take longer than 1-2 weeks either way).

No it took longer. Is it appropriate to phone again? Or should I write a mail? And should I contact her (the person who looked over the review) or my mentor? How would I kindly ask again without sounding annoyed or trying to blame someone?

Comment: How long has been (total time) since your "mentor" did the review and now?

Comment: @Brian He had the review finished on my last workday and handed it in to the other women. that was 27th march

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise calling this person near the end of their working day and saying something like the following:

> Hello X, I hope I'm not disturbing you? I understand that you're probably very busy, but I was wondering if you have any news for me regarding my internship review as it is slowly starting to become more urgent. Ideally, I'd need it before *[due date]* but I'd like to turn it in as soon as I can so that there is still time to make adjustments if the school requires us to.

You don't seem to be bothering her excessively so it is definitely appropriate to follow up on the situation. It can help your case to tell her when the paperwork is due and to let her know why ideally you'd like to have it sooner. There's always a chance that this has slipped her mind, especially since your story leads me to believe it was almost finalised.

Comment: +1 for needing it by *due date*. Really brings it home that the OP needs it by a certain date instead of leaving it floating around to "get there when it gets there".

Comment: I got an email the day after I posted with the confirmation either way, didn't have to call. The internship wasn't for school, but that doesn't make a difference to the answer

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate to phone again?

Absolutely. Contact whomever is in charge of getting your review to you. Taking 5 weeks to get an internship review done seems a bit excessive to me. Just keep your tone professional on the call.

> "Hello and good to speak with you again! I was wondering if my internship review has been completed? Things have changed since we last spoke and while it is not urgent yet, it is becoming more so every day. When can I expect it in the mail?

This puts the emphasis on the review instead of on whomever is supposed to complete it.